# Including bootstrap in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to include bootstrap in an HTML file..

I am using this code and it doesn't work ..

```
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.2.0" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" />
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" data-semver="3.1.1" data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
    asdf
    <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
    sadf
    <!--Body content-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to use the CDNs

Comment: Please elaborate on what "it doesn't work" means. Checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: You're including jquery and bootstrap twice each (and different versions). Go to http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ head down to basic template and change the src= to use CDNs.

Comment: Where's the !DOCTYPE? and the <title> ? I don't think bootstrap works in Quircksmode!

Answer (score 1):

You've included bootstrap 3. Responsive grid class must be col-md-2 and col-md-10
If you launch this file from file system, you have to add http: on all src="//..."

Change

```
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It will work with this code :

```
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.2.0" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" />
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" data-semver="3.1.1" data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">
    asdf
    <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
    sadf
    <!--Body content-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no.. i copy pasted in plunker and it doesn't work at all

Comment: what output do you get .. two divs in the same row or new ones?? i am getting two divs in two rows

Comment: @Brian fluid row fixed.

Comment: Witch browser are you using ?

Comment: hey that's funny .. it works when i open through file system but not on plunker is there a reason?

Comment: Because the plunker window has a small width. If you add col-xs-2 and col-xs-10 it will work on plunker. Like on the above answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need the http: because you are working file based, meaning, you have an html file that you are clicking on and opening in your browser. Once you get going localhost or server you can remove http: so that the website will load the resources whether http or https

```
    <html>

<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.2.0" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                asdf
    <!--Sidebar content-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                sadf
    <!--Body content-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No he is not on some of his resources

Comment: I must be blind, which ones is he not?

Comment: well here's the problem. I tried exactly that code copy pasted into plunker and it doesn't work. it should display the two divs next to each other in the same row and instead it displays each on a new line meaning that the styling is not added.

Comment: I updated my answer, span is for bootstrap 2.3, Bootstrap 3.0 uses a new mobile first grid system with different classes, col-lg-1, col-md-1, col-sm-1

Comment: i copy pasted the above code into plunker and it doesn't work

Comment: You had multiple issues with your code, one is you need http when working file base, two you had duplicate lib resources and three, you weren't using the correct bootstrap 3 classes, there is no such thing as fluid anymore with bootstrap 3, because of mobile first.

Comment: In plunker you need col-sm-2 and col-sm-10 because the view is such a small width